# Unable to unzip multipart zip file

Tags: linux, unix, compression, zip, unzip

When I am unzipping a combined multi-part zip file, I am getting error :

`error: invalid zip file with overlapped components (possible zip bomb)`
Initially I thought maybe because of the special characters inside the file. But even after I ran `dos2unix` on the sample input file `Other_advisors-current_02.txt` the error remains the same. Below are the commands I fired to do this. Please help.

```
[hdf-user@hostname1 zip_test]$ ll
total 98124
drwxr-x---. 2 hdf-user hdf-user      4096 Jun 14 03:03 input
-rw-rw----. 1 hdf-user hdf-user 100073472 Jun 14 02:49 Other_advisors-current_02.txt
drwxr-x---. 2 hdf-user hdf-user      4096 Jun 14 03:03 output
[hdf-user@hostname1 zip_test]$ ll input/
total 0
[hdf-user@hostname1 zip_test]$ ll output/
total 0
[hdf-user@hostname1 zip_test]$ zip -s 5m -r input/Other_advisors-current_02.zip Other_advisors-current_02.txt
  adding: Other_advisors-current_02.txt (deflated 90%)
[hdf-user@hostname1 zip_test]$ ll input/
total 10300
-rw-r-----. 1 hdf-user hdf-user 5242880 Jun 14 03:04 Other_advisors-current_02.z01
-rw-r-----. 1 hdf-user hdf-user 5242880 Jun 14 03:04 Other_advisors-current_02.z02
-rw-r-----. 1 hdf-user hdf-user     209 Jun 14 03:04 Other_advisors-current_02.zip
[hdf-user@hostname1 zip_test]$ cd input/
[hdf-user@hostname1 input]$ zip -s 0 Other_advisors-current_02.zip --out ./../output/Other_advisors-current_02.zip
 copying: Other_advisors-current_02.txt
[hdf-user@hostname1 input]$ cd ../output/
[hdf-user@hostname1 output]$ ll
total 10292
-rw-r-----. 1 hdf-user hdf-user 10485877 Jun 14 03:05 Other_advisors-current_02.zip
[hdf-user@hostname1 output]$ unzip Other_advisors-current_02.zip
Archive:  Other_advisors-current_02.zip
  inflating: Other_advisors-current_02.txt
  error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
 bad CRC 1b65d96d  (should be 0ed95e82)
error: invalid zip file with overlapped components (possible zip bomb)
[hdf-user@hostname1 output]$
[hdf-user@hostname1 input]$ zip -FF Other_advisors-current_02.zip --out existing.zip
Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
 Found end record (EOCDR) - says expect 3 splits
Scanning for entries...
  Found spanning marker - expected as this is split (multi-disk) archive...
 copying: Other_advisors-current_02.txt  (10485757 bytes)
        zip warning: entry truncated: Other_advisors-current_02.txt
        zip warning: expected compressed/stored size 10485757, actual 10485669
Central Directory found...
no local entry: Other_advisors-current_02.txt
EOCDR found ( 3    187)...
        zip warning: zip file empty
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure it's a valid zip file, *not* a Zip bomb, i.e. a file designed to put he PC in to an infiinite loop? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb  2. You can use other compression tools, such as p7zip, http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/, to try to open the archive.

Comment: Its is a valid zip file.. You see I created it  on the fly using the zip command. It is originally a 168 MB file which after zipping results in a 17 MB file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could solve this was by concatenating all files and then unzipping it like below:

```
cat Other_advisors-current_02.z01 Other_advisors-current_02.z02 Other_advisors-current_02.zip > Output.zip

unzip Output.zip
```